# Marker multiple snippet Google Maps API 2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to create a marker with multiple lines on my snippet, the thing that I've tried is :

```
  Marker mjdd1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(JDD1)
           .title(s)
           .snippet("C/ Palim, 2-5-Ctra.N-II \n"+ "08330 sads de Mar \n" + "Lunes - Sábado \n" + "09:15 - 21:15 "
                   )

           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_mapa)));
```

But it shwos all in one line, the other thing that i've tried is put the title with other color doing :

```
String s="Clows" ;
    SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(s);
    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 5, 0);
```

But it shows black...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to use `Custom info windows` for `Google Maps Android API v2`

To do this, you must create a concrete implementation of the `InfoWindowAdapter` interface and then call `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()` with your implementation.

The interface contains two methods for you to implement: `getInfoWindow(Marker)` and `getInfoContents(Marker)`. The API will first call `getInfoWindow(Marker)` and if null is returned, it will then call `getInfoContents(Marker)`. If this also returns null, then the default info window will be used.

For more details, please refer to [here](http://javapapers.com/android/markersgoogle-maps-android-api-v2/), and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows)